# Mirror only one window on a second monitor

Tags: display, screen

[image]

For presentation purposes, I would like to reproduce the above setup in a dual monitor context.

Each color represents one window meaning the two safari windows should belong to their own screen while the code editor window should be mirrored to the external display.

Is that something one can do?